# R using Heatmaps in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a Linux box that runs Shiny
I'm trying to get the code to run for leaflet based on the demos [here](https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-heatmap) and [here](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/demo/) which look brilliant

My code is below which is taken from the rpubs page

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
leaflet(quakes) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  addWebGLHeatmap(lng=~long, lat=~lat, intensity = ~mag, size=60000)
```

I have installed `/home/shiny/nodejs/Leaflet.heat-gh-pages`

When I run the code above I get the map. My data is good because I can plot the markers, but nothing seems to happen when I add the `addWebGLHeatmap` portion.

I am a complete novice at `JS` but is there any additional setup I need to get it running?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? If there's just a blank map it could mean there's problem with your browser is too old or doesn't support WebGL. You can test it here, for example: https://get.webgl.org/

Comment: Hi @chrki, The map loads but the points (the heat mapping aspect of my data) doesnt overlay the OSM map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems i have to register the plugin first in order for it to work as per the github page [here](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92)

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

heatPlugin <- htmlDependency("Leaflet.heat", "99.99.99",
  src = c(href = "http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/"),
  script = "leaflet-heat.js"
)

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds(min(quakes$long), min(quakes$lat), max(quakes$long),     max(quakes$lat)) %>%
  registerPlugin(heatPlugin) %>%
  onRender("function(el, x, data) {
    data = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data);
    data = data.map(function(val) { return [val.lat, val.long, val.mag*100]; });
L.heatLayer(data, {radius: 25}).addTo(this);
  }", data = quakes %>% select(lat, long, mag))
```